# Trying to install mcrypt extension

Tags: mcrypt

I have centos 5.6, php 5.3.6 and nginx as my webserver. I'm trying to install mcrypt and I tried yum install php-mcrypt but it says no package is available. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

5.3.6 means that you didn't install it from a stock repo. You will need to redo the installation procedure you've already performed, except you will need to enable mcrypt support.